# Delete row on click on an alertDialog, using Titanium

Tags: titanium

I'm developping a mobile app using titanium appcelerator. I want to delete a row on a tableview when i click on an alertDialog. here is my code :

```
dataArray = [];                      
//Insert the JSON data to the table view 
for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++){ 
  var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ 
                    title: json[i].nom, 
                    hasChild : true, 
                    obj: json[i].titrePro,
                    obj1: json[i].adresse 
                    }); 
  row.addEventListener('click',function(e){ 
   //$.tableView.deleteRow(e.row);
   var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
   title: 'A propos '+e.row.title,
   message:  '\nTitre Pro : '+e.row.obj+'\n\nAdresse : '+e.row.obj1+'\n', buttonNames: ['Rejeter','Accepter'], cancel: 1 });
   alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
     if(ev.cancel===true) {
        Titanium.API.info( "Accept button was clicked !");
        $.tableView.deleteRow(e.row);
        }
    });
   alertDialog.show();
  });
  dataArray.push(row);     
};                      
$.tableView.setData(dataArray);
```

The error was on the:

```
$.tableView.deleteRow(e.row);
```

When running my app, the `Titanium.API.info( "Accept button was clicked !");` was displayed correctly, but the **deleteRow** does not work!

Comment: Which platform iOS or android?

Comment: using android platform.

Comment: Wahab can you help me about this ? thanks.

Comment: you should not be listening on the `row` you should put the listener on the whole `tableView` it is much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Just replace **if(ev.cancel===true)**  with  **if(ev.index== 1)**

```
alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
     if(ev.index== 1) {
        Titanium.API.info( "Accept button was clicked !");
        $.tableView.deleteRow(e.row);
      }
});
```

Comment: Hi Suraj, i tried with this but each time the row deleted reappers when i click on a second row to delete it !